# The same code is working on local server, but it is not working on web server

Tags: c#, sql-server, webserver, insert-update, localserver

I have been developing a server side(.NET) ios and android application. Besides, In my project there is an "order" process. If a user makes a new order, I get the ordered products as dictionary and convert to JSON string and send it to web service. Then, in the service side, I insert those products into related table and push a notification to related seller device through server side.

This process works fine when I connected to local server. However, when I connected to web server, it doesn't work and insert operations don't occur. I double checked that all of the related database table columns, properties, foreign keys. Moreover, I created an exception table and if the code runs into catch block, I inserted the exception to exception table to catch the  error on web server. But, the code never runs into catch block. I couldn't find that why the code does not run on web server.

Note: It works fine on Android, it doesn't work for ios. Also, I use "Parse" for push notification for ios temporarily.

Could you help me please ?

Thank you for answers,
Best regards

Comment: are any errors being logged in the event viewer of the server? Do you have any indication of where the error is occurring? Are there any installation differences between the local server and the web server (.net version, etc)? Are there any permissions errors?

Comment: There isn't any logged error in event viewer. How can I catch the error on web server alternatively ?

Comment: do you have any indication that the application is being reached on the server at all?

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to log errors to the database, because database connectivity itself can be the cause of a lot of errors. Consider error logging to the Windows event log, or to a local file, instead. You can also use remote debugging http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Yes, I am sure that I reached to server. Because, other web services work fine. @user1666620

Comment: if the problem is inserting records to the database, and no errors are being stored in the database, then could the problem be with connecting to the database? Can you modify your logging to write to a text file instead?